# SPNEGO settings for Firefox and Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, kerberos, websphere-portal, spnego

I'm trying to configure Google Chrome and Firefox to work via SPNEGO/Kerberos with IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 on WAS7, when the client is in a domain other than the one in which need to log in. In IE this can be done by setting "prompt for user name and password", but I can't find any analogue of this setting in FF and GC.

My current FF & GC settings:

FF:

```
 - network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris = domain
 - network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = domain
```

GC:

```
--auth-server-whitelist="*domain"
```

It works only if client is in the same domain in which to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update this... There are settings for Chrome and Firefox that have allowed this for some time.  If you search for "configure chrome firefox spnego" you will get numerous (probably outdated) links.

Nowadays, Chrome, Edge and Firefox use the same registry settings as IE so you no additional config. is required.

Comment: Extra note: for FF:you do need to go to about:config and set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` to the URI.  You can have more than one (comma-separated).

For Chrome, Edge, IE the defaults may work, but, if not, you just set the internet options as described at https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/security-how-to-guides/topics/cm-security-browser-access-kerberos-protected-url.html as for IE.

Answer (score -1):

This is intended behaviour for SPNEGO/Kerberos/GSS-API. In works with domain accounts only.

Comment: But why it works in Internet Explorer? In this case, the user explicitly enters his userPrincipalName (login@domain) and password of domain account, and as a result he successfully authenticated.

Comment: Inspect the response headers. If Auth Basic is requested, firefox should prompt too. Anything else is IE specific and not standard.

Comment: Www-Authenticate:Negotiate (Kerberos) has worked with FireFox an Chrome for some time.